# Problems with $_POST and variable

Tags: post

I'm new to html and php and so on... Just self studying some things. Now I have a little problem with this form (inside of "auswahlmenue.php"):

```
<form action="liste.php" method="post"> 
        Mitarbeiter  
        <select name="mitarbeiter"> 
            <?php 

              // SQL-Query erzeugen
              require "sql.php";
              $sql01 = "SELECT NAME FROM felder ORDER BY name"; 
              $result = mysql_query($sql01); 

              // für jeden Eintrag ein Option-Tag erstellen                 
              while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
                  echo '<option value="'.$row['ID'].'"'.($_POST['NAME'] == $row['ID'] ? " selected": "").'>'.$row['NAME'].'</option>'; 
              } 
            ?>
        </select> 
        <input type="submit" value="Senden" /> 
    </form>
```

Everything works fine. I see my dropdown list and I can select my name... Now I want to check my selection at this page (liste.php):

```
<?require "auswahlmenue.php";if(isset($_POST['mitarbeiter']) ) {$listemid=$_POST["mitarbeiter"];echo "Test $listenmid";}else {echo "Es wurden keine Werte übergeben";}?>
```

It doesn't print out my variable $listenmid... What am I getting wrong?

Thank you very much for your help...

Comment: you are missing `php` at `<?require "ausw...`

Comment: changed it to <?php but nothing it doesn't show me my selected item... I tried to show me the content of $_POST[mitarbeiter] but it's empty. So it looks like I don't get the variable to be filled

Comment: Before submiting the form, could you inspect the page source code and paste here what the final form html looks like?

Comment: `<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Dropdown</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <form action="liste.php" method="post"> 
            Mitarbeiter  
            <select name="mitarbeiter"> 
                <option value="" selected>name1</option><option value="" selected>name2</option><option value="" selected>name3</option><option value="" selected>name4</option><option value="" selected>name5</option>            </select> 
            <input type="submit" value="Senden" /> 
        </form> 
    </body> 
</html>`

Comment: Hmmm... Looks like I don't have any values in the form.

Comment: Indeed, you are using `$row['ID']` when you are retrieving only `NAME`. Modify your query to retrieve `ID` as well.